# PHP STR2VAR Creater function

Tags: php, variables

```
   <?php function STR2VAR($strs){
     $a = explode(',',$strs);
     foreach($a as $key) {
            $$key =  $_GET[$key];
            }
        }
    STR2VAR('exam1,exam2,exam3');    
     echo $exam1;
?>
```

this not working why for? giving undefined exam1
how web define in function to awayside using

Comment: you set the vars in a function, they aren't global

Comment: I think you are creating a variable inside of a function, so that   variable only live in that function.

Comment: Why you dont use $_GET array directly, another way is to pass an array that will contain the values...  I think your function is useless.

Comment: i must work like this.
define inside function using public variable

Comment: It certainly *must* not. There are better ways for doing whatever you think you need to do here.

Answer (score 0):

As I told you in my comment this is a variable scope issue, variables that you declare and use into a function only live in that function, in order to make the variable live outside of that function you will have to precede its declaration with `global`

This is how you fix your code :

```
function STR2VAR($strs){
     $a = explode(',',$strs);
     foreach($a as $key) {
           global  $$key;
         $$key =  'test';
            }

        }
    STR2VAR('exam1,exam2,exam3');    
     echo $exam1;
```

Comment: Yes you can read my previous comments that I made. this function is useless.

Answer (score -2):

After your function is being executed, variable variables become out of scope, hence segmentation fault/null reference. Declare your `$$` variable `global` or use an existing array for assignment.

An example fix:

```
    $my_array = array();

    function STR2VAR($strs) {
        global $my_array;
        $a = explode(',',$strs);
        foreach($a as $key) {
            $my_array[$key] =  $_GET[$key];
        }
    }

    STR2VAR('exam1,exam2,exam3');    
    echo $my_array['exam1'];
```

?>

Comment: $myarray in your example still isn't global, so won't solve the problem

Comment: Consider it is declared in outermost scope.

Comment: PHP doesn't work that way. Outermost scope is global variables, which must be imported with `global` to use in a function, regardless where they are first mentioned.

Comment: Your edit is still incorrect: `global` *imports* a variable into the current function scope. Specifying `global` *outside* the function will just import a variable from global scope into global scope - i.e. do nothing.